# How to know who is submitting a form in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an app where a user must be logged in to post an advertisement visible to others. How can I associate that person's unique id to that posting? Is there a way to fetch their attributes once they are signed in?

edit: each user submits a form to add the posting to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each user will have a unique value in the :APP_USER [substitution string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmdb/understanding-substitution-strings.html#GUID-3AFC7346-902C-4DCA-8D28-960BD8FC6628).

Answer (score 3):

I have the practice of putting triggers on every remotely important table.

Each of these tables includes 4 fields, date of insert, user who inserted, date of last change, user of last change.

Then the trigger just fills these fields with SYSDATE and APP_USER.

This way we get to see who inserted each data, and if it was later changed, we also see that.

For more important tables you should also have history, either the built in history, or a table into which each change is logged.